# Are there badges for Angular 2?

Tags: angular, badge

Hopefully this isn't a duplicate, I tried checking. 
I'm sure other Angular2 developers have ran into this. I need a simple badge that can bind to numeric data, such as displaying `someArray.length` as a number. I know [Ionic 2 has badges](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#badges) and I think [AngularMaterial 1 has badges](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4236) or has discussed them. Even an external package compatible with Angular2 would be fine, but I can't find any. Will I need to code/style DIY badges or has someone done this for Angular2?

Comment: I really don't see why people vote to close this question. OP asks for an UI component. How is this off-topic?

Comment: Thanks @Stilgar , StackOverflow feels like the Twilight Zone sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking for this as well and found this
http://www.angulartypescript.com/angular-2-badges-salesforce/

It looks like they use a library called ng-lightning to create badges.
https://github.com/ng-lightning/ng-lightning

I am about to try it out.

EDIT:  ng-lightning looks to be only for RC4 for now.  I put in a request to update to RC5.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like [Badges in Angular-Material are on their way](https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/7483)!

Comment: It will only be available on release v6.